Strange 0 ETH transactions that don't go to contracts with structured message
I was researching EOA->EOA transactions that took more than 21k gas when I found multiple transactions that don't transfer any ETH value nor do they call a contract but have a not null data field. If you consider that data field to be utf8, it sometimes contains structured data like this:
5.85 eth -> 45.06472 bnb(bsc) fromhash: 0x5734f607fd4ed5e0d37e8f6774faf331a6985a1574d67c5a0b52d7bd94f6d7b9 tohash: 0x26776da327f522b636fac41112b08d90bb3e466c984183d88f4402d145c4d374

Concretely, over 2500 rows are returned for the following dune query:
SELECT
  block_time,
  block_number,
  gas_used,
  'from',
  to,
  FROM_UTF8(data) AS msg
FROM ethereum.transactions
WHERE
  success = true
  AND value = 0
  AND position('fromhash:' IN from_utf8(data)) > 0
  AND position('tohash:' IN from_utf8(data)) > 0

Some other samples:
18.5 usdt(matic) -> 18.216868 usdt(bsc) fromhash: 0xc16d54f5754aadef9ebfc959ac252a92d50343017e3c9cc4133b4b423c7021a1 tohash: 0xdfbeb1d5cd01459d61d5b242fbf8efc69ea141951b96c8d6be3e3ba04ed3d0ca
5.85 eth -> 45.06472 bnb(bsc) fromhash: 0x5734f607fd4ed5e0d37e8f6774faf331a6985a1574d67c5a0b52d7bd94f6d7b9 tohash: 0x26776da327f522b636fac41112b08d90bb3e466c984183d88f4402d145c4d374
10.165616 eth -> 18611.996123 usdt(tron) fromhash: 0x25bca2044ad8f7889f94e4161abdc440f2538034685d89eaf390669bef7006fd tohash: 66cd1adde66f1b4096fe61afa411bea1adfa91b9acd9f39bca7b0767523d3baa

For more information, I plotted the amount of these messages sent daily here:

It mainly starts in july 2023.
Additionally, most of the messages have been created by just two addresses: 0xa15ede0cf46c12e4a79632df33ba1b2f428e5d15 (1600 messages) and 0x8e3e5eec92c401d26b9e5eb17cba828772736558 (1300 messages).
What are these? Is this some kind of ERC? Is this an off-chain  or L2 protocol?

That's when inscriptions launched on ethereum. Basically instead of minting a NFT using a smart contract, they would store the essential information on calldata. They are similar to Bitcoin's ordinals.

I looked at ethscriptions' docs and they all are JSON data. Is this some other kind of inscription?
